# In html, how can I hyperlink a portion of a text that is outputted by a token?

Tags: html, hyperlink, token, dotnetnuke

I'm working on a template editor using HTML, and have a token that generates a series of text. For example if I put in [TOKEN1], that will generate "Text 1, Text 2, Text 3]

I was wondering how I can apply a hyperlink (a href) to each text individually. I'm not really familiar with coding and wasn't sure if there was a way to apply an argument using something like if you see 1 comma, end hyperlink, or like, start hyperlink if you see first comma, and then till second comma.

Thank you!

Comment: You can probably do this with javascript.  Can you post an exact example of the html produced by the HTML module?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. What exactly should I provide you with? In the template editor I am using <span>TEXT</span><a href="[Token1]" target="_blank">[Token2]</a>. Token1 is a link and token2, can be a series of text (ex. text 1, or text 1, text 2. etc)